# Is it safe to reuse local storage credentials to login in Ionic app?

Tags: security, authentication, ionic-framework, local-storage, ionic4

I'm developing an Ionic app that handles authentication like follows:

1. When opening the app, the user is required to enter his credentials (login, password)
2. Once done, the app will request a JWT token from the server
3. The username, password and JWT token are then stored in the user's local storage (using @ionic-native/storage)
4. Later on, if the user re-open the app, the authentication will be done automatically

   - Reuse the token from local storage (if not expired)
   - Or request a new one with the credentials stored in local storage

All of this is to automate authentication and avoid asking the user to authenticate every time.

**Is that implementation safe?**
**If not, what are the risks?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A cookie would be much better than local storage

> If you store it inside localStorage, it's accessible by any script
>   inside your page (which is as bad as it sounds as an XSS attack can
>   let an external attacker get access to the token).

https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Then whether it is persisted or not after window close is a matter of the sensitivity of the data and desired user experience. There's some good advice on the matter at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: Thanks @chrismclarke. I've just ran into another cordova plugin ([cordova-plugin-secure-storage](https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage)) which seems to fit perfectly, although it's not maintained anymore :(

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were making a PWA and hadn't thought about cordova. I think the system for working with cookies in cordova webview is non-standard, but possibly the following repo might be of use in case the other plugin doesn't work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cookiemaster

Comment: Otherwise a happy medium might be to use indexeddb - slighly overkill for storing a single string, but if you are planning to use Ionic Storage for other things then could be a good option